# Monotouch Dialog kills my UINavigationController back button

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I'm sure I'm doing something dumb here, but I can't see it.  When I push a DialogViewController onto the navigation stack, my Back button disappears.

My push code is this:

```
//launch an inspection VC
var vc = new FacilityInspectionListViewController ();
this.NavigationController.PushViewController (vc, true);
```

and my dialog code is this:

```
    public FacilityInspectionListViewController () : base(UITableViewStyle.Plain, null) 
    {
        var root = new RootElement ("Root") 
        {
            new Section () 
            {
                new StringElement ("Facility 1", () => {DoSomething();}),
                new StringElement ("Facility 2", () => {DoSomething()}),
                new StringElement ("Facility 3", () => {DoSomething();})
            }
        };

        base.Root = root;
    }
```

But when I do this, the pushed screen has no Back button:

[image: Screenshot]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Overwrite the constructor for your Dialog viewcontroller to set the **pushing** parameter to true.

1. Stock Monotouch dialog:

   ```
   public partial class DetailedZenoView : DialogViewController {
       public DetailedZenoView () : base (null, true) {
       }
   ...
   ```
2. MvvmCross (CrossUI) dialog:

   ```
   public partial class DetailedZenoView : MvxDialogViewController {
       public DetailedZenoView () : base ((UITableViewStyle)1, null, true) {
       }
   ...
   ```

Comment: Excellent answer, even including the MvvmCross solution! @JoshuaFrank, unless you have made other observations regarding the validity of this answer, I strongly recommend that you accept it.

Comment: That's odd, I thought I had accepted it. Anyway, just did so now.